# Is It Possible To Add Click Events To An Icon Within A ListView Tile?

Tags: listview, objectlistview

I have overridden the draw event of a list view to draw my own individual tiles.  On each tile I want to place an icon of a phone and attach a click event to it so a user can click on the little icon (within a tiled listview item) and it executes a command.

I'd also like to implement a hover type scenario where I can change icon colours or text colour when the mouse hovers over an icon.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

I am using the ObjectListView in tile view if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using `ObjectListView's` `ItemRenderer` to custom draw the tiles.

Each renderer has a `HitTest()` method. In your renderer, override this method and when the given point is over something interesting, change the `OlvListViewHitTestInfo.HitTestLocation` to be `UserDefined` and `OlvListViewHitTestInfo.UserData` to be whatever you want (e.g. "phone").

`ObjectListView.MouseMoveHitTest` holds the hit test information from the last mouse move.

Setup a `MouseUp` event handler, and in that handler, look at `MouseMoveHitTest.HitTestLocation` and `MouseMoveHitTest.UserData` properties to see if the mouse was over your phone when it was clicked.

Similarly, when you are drawing your tile, you can use those same properties to decide whether to draw the phone highlighted or not.

Comment: thanks very much for the reply.  I am excited to try and get this to work.  Do you have some kind of example so I can understand it completely.  I understand what you mean, I'm just not sure on how to set it up properly.  Thanks

Comment: Nevermind, I almost have this working now thanks.  The only issue I have now is that I have to click each tile item twice for it to work.  The first time I click it, the `MouseMoveHitTest.UserData` returns nothing, but the second time it returns my string value.